# Launch root bin startup

Tags: fedora, vpn

Good evening, everyone,

I want [Mullvad](https://mullvad.net/fr/guides/installing-mullvad-client-linux/) to launch when Fedora 18 starts as root.

Here is the command I put in /etc/rc.local :

```
export MULLVAD_USE_GTK3=yes && exec /usr/bin/mullvad
exit 0
```

The problem is that it doesn't work...

Do you have any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: No particular reason, I tried without exec but it doesn't work either.